# Get specific information from a database to display on webiste

Tags: php, mysql

I have got it to call all information I want to show on the website but I actually only need certain data showing such as only things with project id of 1.

I've tried a few different while functions.

```
//creating connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, user_id, project_id, hours FROM hours_worked";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: This is basic SQL. Have you researched this at all?

Comment: Yes believe it or not I did some research but I couldn't find the answer and everything I tried broke it. Thank you so much for being constructive and helping me out!

Comment: Try using a "WHERE" clause....looking something like
$sql = "SELECT id, user_id, project_id, hours FROM hours_worked WHERE project_id = 1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your sql query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT  id, user_id, project_id, hours FROM hours_worked WHERE project_id ='".$project_id."';
```

Change the WHERE clause according to your need.
If you want to display just the records associated with a particular user, then change the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE user_id = *ENTER USER ID HERE*
```

Comment: Perfect I was just about to comment that I figured it out!      $sql = "SELECT id, user_id, project_id, hours FROM hours_worked WHERE project_id = 1";

Comment: Glad to know that